Why the keras.models.save_model() method does not save the weigths when the model is defined in a custom keras.Model class?
I am trying to train, save and load back a model defined in a custom class inherited from keras.Model.
The definition and training is working fine. I save the trained model in the '.keras' format. When I load back the model, the architecture is preserved but the weights of each layer are missing. Here is a code example reproducing the issue :
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
class dummyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, dense_size, **kwargs):
        
        self.dense_size = dense_size
        super().__init__(**kwargs) 

  
    def build(self):
        self.layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.dense_size) 
        self.layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.dense_size)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.layer1(inputs)
        out = self.layer2(x)
        return out
    
        
    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
            'dense_size': self.dense_size
        }) 
        return config
      

input = tf.random.normal((100,100,1))
output = tf.random.normal((100,100,1))

model = dummyModel(10) 

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(input, output, epochs=10, batch_size=10)

tf.keras.models.save_model(model, 'dummy.keras')

modelSaved = tf.keras.models.load_model('dummy.keras')

assert model.to_json() == modelSaved.to_json(), "Model architectures are different"

for layer1, layer2 in zip(model.layers, modelSaved.layers):
    weights1 = layer1.get_weights()
    weights2 = layer2.get_weights()
    if weights1 != []: 
        assert weights2, f"{layer2.name} of loaded model has empty weight list" 
    for w1, w2 in zip(weights1, weights2):
        assert np.array_equal(w1, w2), f"Weigths of {layer1.name} are different."

print("Models are identical (architecture and weigths).")

The code throws this assertion error :
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-10-3ff24dc35a83> in <cell line: 46>()
     48     weights2 = layer2.get_weights()
     49     if weights1 != []:
---> 50         assert weights2, f"{layer2.name} of loaded model has empty weight list"
     51     for w1, w2 in zip(weights1, weights2):
     52         assert np.array_equal(w1, w2), f"Weigths of {layer1.name} are different."

AssertionError: dense_2 of loaded model has empty weight list

I tried to use a keras.Sequential model or the Functional API and the weights are saved properly. When the model is defined in a custom class with the appropriate get_config() method, no weights are saved.
Here is a colab link with the same code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1H47N77k5skn9CXp4ijx3sMhGy2EL5iAd#scrollTo=0xy_DDNNO2So

I also had a similar problem before with the serialization of custom layers/models.
I don't know which tf version you are using but there are some versions where you cannot use the .keras extension for saving the whole model and instead, you should use another extension like .ml for example. I also recommend, if you are using the ModelCheckpoint, to always set the flag save_weights_only either to True or False so you know for sure what's being saved.
The serialization was always a pain in the ass to overcome so what I've done and has been working for the past months is to save only the weights of the model (no serialization problems here) and then just create new instances of the model wherever I want and import the weights.
If you really want to save the whole model for whatever reason I see you're not doing any serialization and neither you have an explicit deserialization from_config() class method.
Any non-classical types such as int, float... need to be serialized/deserialized; this includes your Dense layer.
For more info visit https://keras.io/guides/serialization_and_saving/

I'm using tensorflow 2.17.0 which is the latest release so far. I followed the keras guide closely and I don't think you need to serialize the dense_layer attributes because they are not passed to the class as arguments, they are instanciated in the class. With the decorator @tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(), Keras knows where to look to load the dummyObject with the dense_size arguments saved in the config with the get_config() method. Indeed, the loading doesn't throw deserialization error and the dummy model with dense layers is loaded, only the weights are missing.

I found a workaround which is wrapping the model in a Functional one but I would appreciate to understand why this code is not working as I expected.
